# Software solution running locally (if not possible; in the cloud) for communicating and storing result data with APIs

Tags: api, cloud-service, web-server, server

#### The task I want to accomplish

An server-imitating application that will run inside of my computer that acts as a server that runs a script or multiple that are written to interact with APIs([check](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/)). If not possible; in the cloud.

#### Requirements

- It runs in a side of my computer. If not possible; in the cloud.
- It might contain some linux but not that I have to make a word document to write down the comments
- It should be able to be deleted easily
- I should be able to operate kinda-like in AWS - where you can create one server/listener and another then delete one.
- now this:

  - If it is *run on my computer* - It should be a ram usage low application(PC)
  - If it is *run on the cloud* - It should be able to be communicated from me/controlled with ram usage low application(PC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, It is the Postman's Mock server.

It has been working perfectly for my needs, It addresses all my needs.